# Table with two ENUM fields in MySQL, strange behaviour. Is it a bug?

Tags: mysql

after the upgrade to MySQL 5.5 we've noted the strange bug which occurred on the default MySQL server config, it uses the utf16 collation as a default (at least it seems to me)

The strange behaviour is the following.

Create the table with the following two fields

```
CREATE TABLE `aa` (
  `a` ENUM('on','off') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'off',
  `b` ENUM('on','off') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'off'
) CHARACTER SET 'utf16' COLLATE 'utf16_general_ci';
```

Dump the table and the structure will be the following

```
CREATE TABLE `aa` (
  `a` ENUM('o','o') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'o',
  `b` ENUM('o','o') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'o'
)ENGINE=InnoDB
CHARACTER SET 'utf16' COLLATE 'utf16_general_ci';
```

System config

```
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
Linux host 3.2.0-30-virtual #48-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 24 17:12:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mysql-server-5.5 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1    MySQL database server binaries and system database setup
```

Anybody can confirm this?

It seems **NOT** to happen with UTF8 collation, that can be forced to be a default in my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

Comment: Somehow it depends on the character set. Try to use utf8 if you want to use unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be an answer (from the documentation - [Unicode Support](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//charset-unicode.html)):

> Client applications that need to communicate with the server using
>   Unicode should set the client character set accordingly; for example,
>   by issuing a SET NAMES 'utf8' statement. ucs2, utf16, and utf32 cannot
>   be used as a client character set, which means that they do not work
>   for SET NAMES or SET CHARACTER SET. (See Section 10.1.4, “Connection
>   Character Sets and Collations”.)

And one more note (from [Connection Character Sets and Collations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//charset-connection.html)):

> ucs2, utf16, and utf32 cannot be used as a client character set, which
>   means that they do not work for SET NAMES or SET CHARACTER SET.

It looks like utf16 characters were not stored properly.

Comment: so let me understand, I use mysql-workbench to connect to the DB and workbench does `SET NAMES 'utf8'` for client encoding. Then I write a script in utf8 chars and during the transmission to the server of the text `CREATE TABLE aa ( ...` it is converted to UTF16 and THIS IS the problem? Or I miss something? So I should find the option in workbench to set encoding to UTF16?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot set UTF16 to connection. For example command `SET NAMES utf16` will raise an error.